# Обработка форм JS/Python

Tags: javascript, form, flask

Есть сайт с формой. Данные формы должна обрабатываться на сервере, но при клике на кнопку сабмит обновляется страница. Нужно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку данные отправлялись на сервер, а также добавлялись в таблицу на сайте.
Напишу я добавление данных через JS, а как отправлять данные на сервер, не обновляя страницу? Или есть болле изящное решение?
На сервере Python/Flask

Comment: Отлично. поменя submit на button и страница не обновляется!

Comment: ну конечно, `submit` отправляет данные формы на сервер, а `button` это просто кнопка, она на форму будет влиять только тогда, когда сам разработчик напишет для неё функционал